Jquery Autocomplete conflict with minLength and selection of ui.item.label
when I click on the empty search bar, it shows all results, but it won't work when I click on any one of the results on the pop up list. Here is my code with Jquery Autocomplete:
$('#search').autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            let term = request.term;
            let data = handleAutocomplete(term); //your custom handling
            response(data);
        },
        minLength:0,/**/       /*show all options on focus, but conflict with click droplist option*/
        select: function(event, ui){
            if(ui.item){
                console.log('select', ui.item.label);
                return ui.item.label;
            }
            else{
                console.log('select with null value');
            }
        }, /*"get automatically value on focus if no values selected"*/
        change: function(event, ui){
            let searched = this.value;
            console.log("Searched: " + searched);
            if(ui.item){
                console.log('change', ui.item.id);
            }else{
                console.log('change with null value');
                let result = categories.filter(function( value ) {
                    return value.toLowerCase().indexOf(searched.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
                });
                if(result.length>0){
                    $(this).val(result[0]);
                }
                else{
                    //clear the autocomplete
                    $(this).val("");
                }
                
            }
        }
    }).focus(function(){ 
        $(this).autocomplete('search', $(this).val()); /*show all options on focus*/
});

